# Could someone help me to correct my loop?

Tags: php, html, loops, insert, radio-button

Basically I have to do a survey and get all values of the selected radio button at each row, I got some values but then I get errors.

In every row you have a set of 5 radio buttons .

So what is the problem with my loop ?

I got this error btw :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Foredeck\foredeck_insert_client.php on line 55
...
Notice: Undefined offset: 163 in C:\wamp\www\Foredeck\foredeck_insert_client.php on line 55
```

So I need to know how I could stop my loop. The condition could be "If I don't have anymore questions or row to read stop the insert".

I would like to highlight that the name of my radio button set is a variable incremented to not get conflicts beetween different sets of radio buttons at each row.

```
<?php
/**
 * Insert
 */
$link = Mysqli_connect($host, $login, $pass, $dbname);
$s    = 0;
$un   = 1;
$id   = 0;

if (isset($_POST["bouton11"])) {
    while ($s <= $un) {
        $choix = $_POST["$un"];

        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $login, $pass, $dbname);

        $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix)  VALUES('$choix') ";

        $un = $un + 1;
        $s++;

        mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer);

    }

}
?>

<?php
/**
 * Form
 */
if ($id != "" && $Nom != "" && $Prenom != "" && $Email != "") {

    $recherche = "SELECT Ref,Question,Choix,Commentara FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id'";

    mysqli_query($link, $recherche);

    $un = 0;

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $recherche);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $Ref      = $row["Ref"]; /*Line 55*/
        $Question = $row["Question"];

        $un = $un + 1;

        echo " <tr bgcolor=\"white\">

             <td>$Question position: $un </td>
             <td>
             <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">
             <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"2\">
             <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"1\">
             <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\"  value = \"0\">
             <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"0\">
             </td>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what your code shows,
I would simply catch the amount of questions you fetched and use it as a condition:

```
...

$un = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $recherche);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) && $un < $num_results) {

...
```

Also, the first query in your form `mysqli_query($link, $recherche);` has no utility as you don't store the result. This one can be removed.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please post the entire code as the code you submitted isn't complete.

Comment: in the insert part ?

Comment: No, the form part.

Comment: When your query is an insert, you don't need to check the results (if you don't want to handle errors). But when you query for a select you need to store the result somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The While loop is essentially printing the same name value in the HTML, why not try something like:

```
<input type=\"radio\" name =\"{$un}[]\" id =\"un4\" value = \"3\">
<input type=\"radio\" name =\"{$un}[]\" id =\"un3\" value = \"2\">
<input type=\"radio\" name =\"{$un}[]\" id =\"un2\" value = \"1\">
<input type=\"radio\" name =\"{$un}[]\" id =\"un1\"  value = \"0\">
<input type=\"radio\" name =\"{$un}[]\" id =\"un0\" value = \"0\">
```

I've also noticed a duplicate input type radio above.

I would advice using `$un++;` instead of `$un = $un + 1;`, I know the latter is more readable, but is uncommon in many modern programming languages.

Also give each HTML element a unique ID value on that page as I have done above, especially if you intend to interact with those elements in JavaScript or jQuery. When your data is posted, see it with:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, 1) . '</pre>';
}
```

That should go at the top of the place that you're posting to, (`form action="myaction.php"`) for instance.

Comment: so the completed code will be like ? i m french  and english is not my first language . And yes it for duplicate it s normal because the real value is ''PA" mean can t be apply to this question because of the situation but value is 0 when you count the mark of the survey .

Comment: Unfortunately as I don't exactly know what you're trying to achieve, I can't give you a full working example. I'd need a dump of your database and other such things to debug this properly, but you could try this in your <input type="radio"...> near the bottom of your script: `<input type=\"radio\" name =\"" . ++$un . "\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">`, that will increase the numeric value of your $un variable in each input radio as having duplicate names on an input will cause problems, as will duplicate id on the same element.

Comment: To see how `++$un` works, look at the example here: [link](http://ideone.com/dWYUcd)

Comment: The purpose of the programme is to read every row to see which radio button is selected to a question and then save the value of the radio button in the database . Let's say the form is like  question // radio button set  // commentary .

Comment: If all radio buttons have the same name attribute and same id attribute on the HTML element, how will you tell them apart? This is something that should be fixed first and will make it easier to distinguish between one radio button and another. Give each radio button a relevant distinct name value and a unique id value. I would avoid using only number values for either. `name="respondre1" id="respondre1"` ... `name="respondre4" id="respondre4"` is better. It's perfectly acceptable to have the same name and id on an input HTML element as they are intended for different purposes.

Comment: Ok but the problem is that i will get conflict beetween radio buttons in the other set , let  s say if i checked the radio button 1 of the radio button set  at row 1 and checked ratio button 1 of the radio button set  at row 2 of my table it will uncheck the first radio button at row 1 .

Comment: By the way it s working now it s inserting all radio button value for each row but when i don t have any more question in my database then it say : Notice: Undefined offset: 5 ( Because they were only 4 question in database ) so now i need to fin a way to stop the insert when i don t have anymore question in my database to not get this error

Comment: or maybe should i use a for each instead of a while for the insert part ?